# VS2010, CSS intellisense not showing id- or class names

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Should intellisense trigger on typing a # or . in a css file (to list the class/id names)?  I get intellisense inside the curly brackets, but not for the classes and id's. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but the VS 2010 CSS editor does not do it.

In fact, what you find is the opposite for classes: when typing class=" in an html tag, you will get a list of the classes defined in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

1 -  your controller must be an asp.net control and runat="server" (, not the html control)
2 - it just applied on classed (, not elements Id :D )